# Script dosen't work on content page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a script on content page which dosen't work. If I use script on normal page without master page it works. Can someone help please

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site2.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="MojSajt.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function ShowpImagePreview(input) {
          if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function (e) {
                  $('#ImgPrv').attr('src', e.target.result);
              }
              reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
          }
      }
    </script>
        
            <div >
            <asp:Image ID="ImgPrv" Height="80px" Width="80px" runat="server" /><br />
            <asp:FileUpload ID="flupImage" runat="server" onchange="ShowpImagePreview(this);" />
            </div>
   
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please research how MasterPages effect the **rendered** `id` property of HTML elements.  That will explain why you can find `#ImgPrv` on a normal page, but not if using MasterPages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your js to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           function ShowpImagePreview(input) {
              if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                  var reader = new FileReader();
                  reader.onload = function (e) {
                      $('#ImgPrv').attr('src', e.target.result);
                  }
                  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
              }
            }
        });
```

Change your image control code to

```
<asp:Image ID="ImgPrv" Height="80px" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="80px" runat="server" /><br />
```

When the control is rendered it changes the control ID to reflect the path of the content holders or the parent control in the ID. The `ClientIDMode="Static"` will keep the ID unchanged.